# Add if else condition to close and open HTML element inside ng-repeat using AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am making a dynamic menu by getting menu data through API. successfully got the API data and rendered in Html. but my problem is I have some challenging structure in my Html. I need to close the **UL** element after 4th **LI** element and I am unable to do it.

I tried to put ternary condition inside my ng-repeat and the condition is working but I couldn't put Html element as `</ul><ul>` inside condition.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav id="topMenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="tl_dd" data-ng-repeat="headerMenu in headerMenu">
                <a href="{{headerMenu.url != ''?headerMenu.url:'javascript:;'}}" >{{headerMenu.menu_title}}</a>
                <div class="dd clear">
                    <ul>
                        <li data-ng-repeat="submenu in headerMenu.submenu">
                            <a href="{{submenu.url}}">{{submenu.title}}</a>
                         <!--Need to close ul here after every 4th li element-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You could get the array length and can use ng-if.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be a lot more easier for you to move ng-repeat to ul to let ng-repeat handle rendering in groups of four instead of manually trying to play with opening and closing html tags. You can try something like the following to achieve that.

js

```
  $scope.getNumber = function(data,numberOfItems) {
    if(data.length % numberOfItems === 0)
      return new Array(data.length / numberOfItems);
    else
      return new Array(Math.floor(data.length/numberOfItems) + 1);   
  }

  $scope.getData = function(data,index,numberOfItems){
    var temp = data;
    return temp.slice(index * numberOfItems,index * numberOfItems + numberOfItems);
  }
```

html

```
<div class="dd clear">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in getNumber(data,4) track by $index">
        <li data-ng-repeat="name in getData(data,$index,4)">
            {{name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/afUBQAqdmWk82GOPgxqk?p=preview)**

Comment: I'm glad I could help.